# Proguard 5.2.1 Unexpected error while evaluating instruction

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, proguard, obfuscation

I'm getting following strange errors when running proguard on my jar, it use to work fine with JDK 7 but recently we upgraded to JDK 8 and it failing during optimization.

We've tried using the latest version of Proguard and even the beta version (5.3) but we experience the same error.

```
Optimizing...
Unexpected error while evaluating instruction:
  Class       = [com/abc/server/LinkedItem]
  Method      = [createEntityLogForLinkedItems(Ljava/sql/Connection;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/blient/util/ResourceBundle;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;ZILjava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/String;]
  Instruction = [2050] aload v17
  Exception   = [java.lang.NullPointerException] (null)
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
  Class       = [com/abc/server/LinkedItem]
  Method      = [createEntityLogForLinkedItems(Ljava/sql/Connection;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/blient/util/ResourceBundle;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;ZILjava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/String;]
  Exception   = [java.lang.NullPointerException] (null)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at proguard.evaluation.Variables.aload(Variables.java:263)
        at proguard.evaluation.Processor.visitVariableInstruction(Processor.java:694)
        at proguard.classfile.instruction.VariableInstruction.accept(VariableInstruction.java:306)
        at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateSingleInstructionBlock(PartialEvaluator.java:761)
        at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateInstructionBlock(PartialEvaluator.java:609)
        at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateInstructionBlockAndExceptionHandlers(PartialEvaluator.java:567)
        at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute0(PartialEvaluator.java:271)
        at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute(PartialEvaluator.java:188)
        at proguard.optimize.evaluation.SimpleEnumUseChecker.visitCodeAttribute(SimpleEnumUseChecker.java:115)
        at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.accept(CodeAttribute.java:101)
        at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.attributesAccept(ProgramMethod.java:79)
        at proguard.classfile.attribute.visitor.AllAttributeVisitor.visitProgramMember(AllAttributeVisitor.java:95)
        at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitProgramMethod(SimplifiedVisitor.java:92)
        at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.accept(ProgramMethod.java:71)
        at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.methodsAccept(ProgramClass.java:516)
        at proguard.optimize.evaluation.SimpleEnumUseChecker.visitProgramClass(SimpleEnumUseChecker.java:102)
        at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:358)
        at proguard.classfile.ClassPool.classesAccept(ClassPool.java:124)
        at proguard.optimize.Optimizer.execute(Optimizer.java:389)
        at proguard.ProGuard.optimize(ProGuard.java:328)
        at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:127)
        at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:538)
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be filed as in issue in ProGuard's issue tracker?

Comment: Would you mind posting the bytecode of the method causing the crash? You can get the bytecode by dropping your jar in a decompiler like Luyten and changing the settings to view bytecode rather than java. The method in question is 'com/abc/server/LinkedItem.createEntityLogForLinkedItems'. It looks like that method may be long [2050 operands] so a pastebin link would be cleaner than an update / comment.

Comment: @DankVader Here is the specific .class file decompiled and viewed as bytecode (using Luyten) http://pastebin.com/P7hBcwUa Thanks!

Comment: Ok so your program looks fine. And I'm assuming you've tested it and it runs. It's failing because in Proguard's prograurd/evaluation/Variables.aloat(int) method. Due to how the aload method is stup up ( this.load(n).referenceValue() ), it throws a NPE because load(n) returns null (Proguard hasn't set the index of that variable to anything). The only solution here I can think of would be to use the -keep and have this class's local variable table untouched. It should skip the step that's crashing. You'll probably want to also send them this crash report so they can work on a fix in the future.

Comment: @DankVader i've tried setting the entire .class in -keep but it didn't seem to help, this is what i tried: -keep com.abc.server.LinkedItem  { *; } .

Comment: Try ticking this option and seeing what happens: http://i.imgur.com/tefGOGR.png (Note what is highlighted)

Comment: @DankVader i've added LocalVariable\*Table to my -keepattributes but it didn't seem to help, this is how it looks -keepattributes *Signature\*,LocalVariable\*Table,*Annotation\*,*InnerClasses\*

Comment: @DankVader i've also tried without the * sign, i.e -keepattributes *Signature\*,LocalVariableTable,*Annotation\*,*InnerClasses\*